# Object of class Slim\Http\Request could not be converted to double

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I'm trying to send a friendship request, combining users ids in one table, but seems i have made somewhere a mistake. Here is the fragment of code:

```
public function sendRequest($user_one_id, $user_two_id, $status, $action_user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO relationship(user_one_id, user_two_id, status, action_user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $user_one_id, $user_two_id, $status, $action_user_id);
    $result = $stmt->execute(); // HERE IS AN ERROR
    $stmt->close();

    if (!$result) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The error i'm getting:

```
Object of class Slim\Http\Request could not be converted to double
```

EDIT:

This is how i'm calling method:

```
$app->post('/send_request', function() use ($app) {

// check for required params
verifyRequiredParams(array('user_one_id', 'user_two_id', 'status', 'action_user_id'));

// reading post params
$user_one_id = $app->request('user_one_id');
$user_two_id = $app->request('user_two_id');
$status = $app->request('status');
$action_user_id = $app->request('action_user_id');
$response = array();

$db = new DbHandler();

$relationship = $db->sendRequest($user_one_id, $user_two_id, $status, $action_user_id);

if ($relationship != NULL) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["request"]["user_one_id"] = $relationship["user_one_id"];
    $response["request"]["user_two_id"] = $relationship["user_two_id"];
    $response["request"]["status"] = $relationship["status"];
    $response["request"]["action_user_id"] = $relationship["action_user_id"];
} else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "An error occurred. Please try again later.";
}
echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: Check out my edited answer.

Comment: I never worked with Slim, but since noone experienced helps... What if you change you closure into: `$app->post('/send_request', function($request) ...` and then retrieve post parameters with `$user_one_id = $request->getParam('user_one_id');`, still same error? This sounds like you're getting something else then post param. Perhaps var_dump of the 4 variables can give you more hint what is the object actually... Hope it helps a little

Comment: Well, it is strange. Row in table get populated, but with values of 1 for every column and in the same time getting an error from up.

Comment: try set parameters with some correct values before call execute

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your `verifyRequiredParams` function? In the code you posted I dont see any conversion of a `Slim\Http\Request` object.

```
$user_one_id = $app->request('user_one_id');
$user_two_id = $app->request('user_two_id');
$status = $app->request('status');
$action_user_id = $app->request('action_user_id');
```

From what I can tell, these are the only lines of code where you do anything with a Slim request object. Can you verify that the values in these variables you are setting are correct? Like `var_dump()` them and put an `exit` in your code and see what it says.

Comment: Function `verifyRequiredParams` works perfect because i have already use it in another requests. I'm testing this using Postman and parameters that i'm sending are this: `user_one_id`, `user_two_id`, `status`, `action_user_id`. When i try to send this, i'm not getting values i have posted. The values i get in table are all 1, 1, 1, 1 and at the same time i'm getting this error: `Object of class Slim\Http\Request could not be converted to double` on this line of code: `$result = $stmt->execute();`

Comment: var_dump() all your variables to be sure you are actually getting values 1, 1, 1 and 1.

Comment: can you `var_dump` the parameters inside `sendRequest` function? If the error is on the `$result = $stmt->execute();` line as you say, then one of the variables that you are inserting has to be a `Slim\Http\Request` object.

Comment: Solved it guys. Thank you for help!

Comment: Im curious, what was it? :)